# Saw this plane in documentary on the Falklands War. What type is that?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

That nose reminds me of ground attackers, but I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks a lot like the FMA Pucará :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_IA_58_Pucar%C3%A1